# how to replace string in between specified quotes php

Tags: php

I have following string

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABVYAAAMACAIAAABAXKuVAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAgAElEQVR4Xu....">
```

Now i want to replace "uploads/imag1.jpeg" to

`"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABVYAAAMACAIAAABAXKuVAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAgAElEQVR4Xu...."`

i try this

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();

$doc->loadHTML('"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABVYAAAMACAIAAABAXKuVAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAgAElEQVR4Xu...."');
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($tags as $t)
{
$t->setAttribute('src','uploads/imag1.jpeg');
echo $doc->saveHTML();
}
```

But this is not working properly. 
i have path following correct path

```
localhost:83/mysite/images/imag1.jpg
```

But My code gives me following wrong path,

```
localhost:83/mysite/image/uploads/imag1.jpg
```

Because of this issue replacement not works proper.

How can i do this replacement.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have tried?

Comment: I am trying hard, but I just don't understand your question. How is `banner4.jpg` related to `imag1.jpg`? What would be a *correct path* (as opposed to the *wrong path* that you mention above)?

Comment: The argument to `loadHTML()` is the HTML source that backs the DOM that you are working with. I just don't see any `img`-tags in there which could be handled by your loop. Calling `saveHTML()` inside the loop's body doesn't make sense to me, either. Other than that: I haven't fully understood how `imag1.jpg` and your base64-encoded image are related. Can you clarify this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution with PHP:

```
<?php 

   echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'. base64_encode(file_get_contents("uploads/imag1.jpeg")) .'"/>;

?>
```

Comment: i want to replace `<img src="uploads/imag1.jpg'" />`